# Accidental infinite while loop in PHP

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, infinite-loop

Hi I have created a while loop but cannot understand why it loops forever. Could somebody please explain why?

```
while ($i<3){
  if ($i=1){
    $x='psu';
  }else if ($i=2){
    $x='cases';
  }
  $sqlcpu = "SELECT * FROM $x WHERE name LIKE '%{$term}%'";
$query = mysqli_query($db, $sqlcpu);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
?><br /> Name: <a  href="productpage<?php $x ?>.php?idcpu=<?php echo $row['id$x'] ?>"><?php echo $row['name'];?></a>
<?php
echo ' Price: &pound;'.$row['price'];
}
  $i++;
}
```

There are other problems with this code but they are not my main concern right now as this loop seems like it should be simple. The variables $x and $i never change after $i=1

Comment: It's difficult to see what's going on. Your indenting and styling is hard to read.

Comment: use == in the if statement. `if (i == 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>if ($i=1)</strike> You're assinging 1 to $i here, instead of comparing 1 and $i, use

```
if ($i==1)
```

instead.

Instead of the for/if-elseif construct you *could* also use

```
foreach( array('psu', 'cases') as $table ) {
    $sqlcpu = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE name LIKE '%{$term}%'";
```

Comment: Just to add. `$i` is always 1 since it's being reassigned to 1 (instead of being checked for equality) every loop iteration.

Comment: And then there are the possible [sql injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php), missing [error handling](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.errno.php) and missing [output encoding](http://docs.php.net/htmlspecialchars)

Comment: Thanks it's been a while since I've used php and I should have noticed that. Unfortunately there is a dulled down snippet of my page meaning I can't use an array but thank you for your advice